# Errors compiling via cmd line

Tags: java, compiler-errors, switch-statement, final

For an entry level java dev interview they asked me to comment on this code and state what will eb printed by the program (not rewrite, so I son't think thats what I should do?) The job starts with a bunch of paid java training. I don't believe they are expecting me to be a genius. I just started learnign java three days ago. I've added comments to the code but I get a mess of errors when I try to compile using jdk 1.8 javac Foo.java.

```
import java.util.ArrayList; //allows use of the class ArrayList within program
public class Foo { //declares new class

    public String FOONAME = "foobar";  //declares new string variable giving a value of foobar

    private final int fooAge = 23; //declares a private int giving it a final value of 23 

    private static final int fooWeight = 150; //declares a private int giving it a final value of 150

    private double fooHeight; //declares a private double variable, 

    private Foo() {}        // declares new constructor setting default initial values          

    public Foo(int age, int weight) {       //declares constructor and defines initial values
        fooAge = age; // initial value of age will be 23
        fooWeight = weight; // initial value of weight will be 150  
    }

    public void main(String args) { //call to main method, every program needs one, no cmd args, and no return necessary        

        Foo foo = new Foo();    //sets a value for the Foo class            

        System.out.println(Foo.FOONAME); //prints foobar in the cmd window

        int a = foo.getAge(); // declares int variable a giving it a value of foo.getAge() which = fooAge = 23      
        int w = foo.getWeight(); // declares int variable w giving it a value of foo.getWeight() which = fooWeight = 150            

        int young = 20; // delcares int variable called young, giving it a value of 20

        switch(a) { // begins the switch statement, relies on a being a constant value
        case young:         // when a = young (never because a is a constant and already set to 23)                 
            System.out.println("Young"); //print young on a new line in the cmd window is the case statement is True
            break;  // seperates the case statements of the switch statement
        case 30: // when a = 30 (Again this won't happen because a is set at a constant that = fooAge = 23)
            System.out.println("MiddleAged");   // print MiddleAged on a new line in the cmd window if the case statement is True
        default: // defines the result if a is anything other than the two cases defined above.
            System.out.println("Old"); // Old will be printed on a new line in the cmd window if the a meets the default requirements
        } // closes switch statement

        if (a > 70) //begins an if statement, if a is greater than 70 (which it won't be because a is again 23 the final fooAge
            System.out.println("Really Old");   // Really Old would print if a were over 70


        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();     //creates a new resizable arrayList class
        names.add("Bob"); //adds a string value to the arraylist 
        names.add("George");//adds a string value to the arraylist 
        names.add("Linda");//adds a string value to the arraylist 
        names.add(young);   // adds the young variable to the array, but its not a string so that can't be right?                       



    } //closes the main method

    private int getAge() { //decalres the getage variable 
        return fooAge; //gives it the fooAge value that is final and previously set to 23
    } // closes getAge Variable declaration 

    public static int getWeight() { // declares getWeight variable 
        return fooWeight;  //gives it the fooWeight variable that is final and previosuly set to 150
    } // closes the getWeight Declration 

    public void setHeight(final double height) { //decalres setHeight variable,  
        fooHeight = height; // gives height a value of fooheight that hasn't been defined yet
        height = null;      // gives height a value of null, which may or may not be allowed for the double data type                       
    } // closes the setHeight variable

}    // closes the the class Foo 

/*
 if compiled it will print foobar on one line and Old on another 
 */
```

my errors

```
C:\temp\MyWork> javac Foo.java                                                

  Foo.java:15: error: cannot assign a value to final variable fooAge                      

        fooAge = age; // initial value of age will be 23                             
   ^                                                           

   Foo.java:16: error: cannot assign a value to final variable fooWeight                      

     fooWeight = weight;     // initial value of weight will be 150                                                                                                  ^                                                            

   Foo.java:23: error: non-static variable FOONAME cannot be referenced from a static context      

             System.out.println(Foo.FOONAME); //prints foobar in the cmd window                                                                                                                    ^                                        

 Foo.java:31: error: constant expression required                               

                 case young:                     // when a = young (never because a is a constant and already set to 23)                                                              ^                                                     

     Foo.java:44: error: cannot find symbol                                 

                         List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();         //creates a new resizable arrayList class                                                                       ^                                                       

          symbol:   class List                                                  

          location: class Foo                                                   

        Foo.java:64: error: incompatible types: <null> cannot be converted to double        

            height = null;         // gives height a value of null, which may or may not be allowed for the double data type                                                                                                                                        ^                                                      6 errors
```

any help would be appreciated, I'm trying to display my ability to problem solve and access available resources including online resources like stack exchange. This would be a lide altering position to get so I'm doing all that I can!

thank you

Comment: final means final, no change when the variable is final, you cannot change it later

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your constructor of Foo`

```
 public Foo(int age, int weight) {     
    fooAge = age; 
    fooWeight = weight; 
 }
```

But these `fooAge` and `fooWeight` are `final`

```
private final int fooAge = 23;
private static final int fooWeight = 150;
```

You can't alter `final` variables. `final` it self has the meaning what is `final` variable.

Solution: you can use non `final` variables.

Next issue..

```
 System.out.println(Foo.FOONAME);  //FOONAME non static you can't call by class
                                   //name non static variables
```

solution: make `FOONAME` static.

Next issue.

```
 switch(a) { 
        case young:  // cases must be constant.
```

In here `young` is not a constant.

Solution: make `young` final.

```
 final int young = 20;
```

Next issue.

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(); // List not imported 
names.add(young); // adding int to String array?
```

Solution: use proper imports.

```
import java.util.List;
```

and

`names.add(String.valueOf(young));`

Next issue.

```
public void setHeight(final double height) {
 fooHeight = height; 
 height = null; // you can't use null for primitive double
 // and also height is final can't change it.
```

Solution:  you can not assign new value to `height`

Comment: he has already had foo so there is misstype. here  System.out.println(Foo.FOONAME); just the op needs to make Foo to foo. how they saw your answer and not mind a good question ?

Comment: I made all the changes outlined, beautiful!!! But now I get an error stating "package Java.util does not exist and another saying cannot find symbol with this code List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Resolved the cannot find symbol by changing List<String> to ArrayList<String> .

Comment: @This_isWater import must be `import java.util.List`. It is `java.util` not `Java.util`

Answer (score 0):

First,  comments are good, but I think you may just have a few too many, making the code slightly un-readable.

Seconds, the manening of `final` means you can not change the variable to point to a new variable, so as you already have

```
private final int fooAge = 23;
```

it means that `fooAge` can not be changed.

if you do not want this functionality  then remove the `final` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues

**First**, you defined a variable as final, but you tried to assign new value to it later.

> In the Java programming language, the **final keyword** is used in several
>   different contexts to define an entity which **cannot later be changed**.

**Second** , if we imagine height was not final, you assigned `fooHeight` value of height and you assign it null why?

```
 public void setHeight(final double height) {   <-- you cannot pass around final variable
        fooHeight = height;  
        height = null;      <--- why did you assing null to height                      
    }
```

Type of `height` is `double` and you tried to assign `null` to it

**Third**, you tired to access no static variable with static method

```
System.out.println(Foo.FOONAME); <-- totally wrong
```

`FOONAME` is a field of your class, so there is need to make object to have access to it

I think you meant this

```
    Foo foo = new Foo();    //sets a value for the Foo class            
    System.out.println(foo.FOONAME); //prints foobar in the cmd window
```

instead of this

```
    Foo foo = new Foo();    //sets a value for the Foo class            
    System.out.println(Foo.FOONAME); //prints foobar in the cmd window
```

**Fourth**, your `a` variable is type int and you have young which does not make sense

```
 switch(a) {  
        case young:
```

**Fifth** issue

you have do not have proper import for `List` interface

```
import java.util.List;
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
public Foo(int age, int weight)
```

don't work, because fooAge and fooWeight are final.

2.

```
  System.out.println(Foo.FOONAME)
```

don't work. because FOONAME not static

3.

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();     //creates a new resizable arrayList class
```

don't work. because only ArrayList is imported

4.

```
height = null;      // gives height a value of null, which may or may not be allowed for the double data type
```

don't work. because "height" is double, not Double. Cannot be null and value of final variable is not changeable.

Comment: In 4th case height is `final`.